# Как в WordPress вывести дату поста в уникальном дизайне

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

Вот есть макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на вордпрес  вывести даду в карточке поста так как в макете?
На данный момент дата отображается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывожу дату с помощью

```
$date = get_the_date();
```

Нужно сделать в таком HTML

```
<div class="date_box">
  <p class="p_1">01 апр</p>
  <p class="p_2">09:00</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте форматирование даты.

```
<div class="date_box">
    <p class="p_1"><?php echo get_the_date( 'd M' ); ?></p>
    <p class="p_2"><?php echo get_the_date( 'H:i' ); ?></p>
</div>
```